# design pattern to implement a set of permissions for a user

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to implement and code the following using desing patterns, or a good object oriented solution:

There is an user class which can contains a variable set of permits, each one enables him to do different action on the application. The idea is to be able tell a certain user object to, for example delete an order, if he has any permits that enable him to do so, do it and if not, to raise an exception.

If someone has a place where to read about this, it's helpfull too.
thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are built in functions for permission in C#/.NET.

The access requirements on a function is set through the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` class, or inside the code with `PrincipalPermission`. To prevent a method from being called unless the current user is a member of the `Administrators` role, the following attribute is used (sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx)):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
static void CheckAdministrator()
{
    Console.WriteLine("User is an administrator");
}
```

Both these checks against the current identity of the calling thread. So what you need to do is to implement the [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) interface to allow your users to be set as the thread identity. Then you can use standard .NET `PrincipalPermission` to check security. It works exactly as you want - if the security demand is not met, an exception is thrown.

Comment: I prefer this type of Principle-Centric approach too, I would recommend you take it one step further and create declaritive and/or imperitive permission objects to encapsulate the PrinciplePermission assertions. This will keep the principle details from leaking out into the rest of the codebase. Keep in mind you don't have to buy-into the larger CAS infrastructure to use this pattern. One caveat though, the WCF security model is very different so ignore if thats where your going. Here is a sample of the pattern. http://www.smelser.net/blog/post/2009/03/09/Why-do-I-need-your-Permission.aspx

Comment: @JoeGeeky it seems that is what i'm looking for, but how do i set an user's permits? Also, these users and user groups has nothing to do with windows UAC users/user groups?

Answer (score 1):

If one user can have multiple permits, each permit allows different execution tasks, then you might wanna have a look at **decorator** pattern.

although it depends a lot on your requirements.